# basic question about user-/role concept in postgres-databases

Tags: postgresql, database-user

I hope this question is specific enough to be allowed and not doomed as opinion-based:

I'm fairly new at administrating postgres databases. My basic approach was to create a new user / role for each real-world user. I thought it would be advantageous for use-cases, where users simultaneously access the same database. However, I realised this has some disadvantages in terms of granting access-right to future tables.

I am now suspecting that my concept (separate user-account for each real-word user ) is not the "usual way". I could imagine, that it is sufficient to have just a generic user / role, and each real-world user uses that same generic role to connect, create, read, write, modify data and tables?

Can postgres handle such a setup just fine even in the case of concurrent read/write-actions? Is this second concept (one user-account for many users) just fine and frequently applied?

Thanks in advance for your help (or for pointing out appropriate www-sources I have missed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically two choices:

1. Your application does the user and permission management itself. Then it typically has a single “application user” in the database.
2. Your application has per-user or per-group database users and handles user and permission management with database means.

Both solutions are fine. The second solution is maybe less commendable if you have lots of users; also, connection pooling usually works better with the first technique.

If you use database users like in the second solution, you should use `NOLOGIN` roles (user groups) in PostgreSQL to carry the permissions, and you assign the named users to the groups as appropriate. That way you don't have to `GRANT` and `REVOKE` a lot of permissions whenever you add or remove a user or change a user's role in the application.

To answer your question, there are no restrictions on concurrency with different database users.